# Can someone recommend a good text editor for Emacs?

Tags: text-editing

I'm looking for a good way to edit text within Emacs. Can someone give some good recommendations for text-editors for Emacs.

Comment: Thumbs up! [gnu emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's a week early.

Comment: @Gilles I’m confused. How could this be off-topic? One of the examples of an on-topic question, given in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , is “How to make Emacs behave like X?” This question is essentially “how do I make Emacs behave like a text editor.” I mean, this person probably doesn’t know much about Emacs, but that’s what Q&A sites are for.

Comment: @TinaRussell Questions closed with a custom comment are [always marked as “off-topic”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic). This post is about Emacs, but it isn't really a question: there's nothing to answer there. “Can someone recommend” is [not a suitable question for Stack Exchange](/help/dont-ask) and “how do I make Emacs behave like a text editor?” is not a useful question because it doesn't have useful answers. I mean, if you take this seriously, the answer is “nothing”. That's not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  Perhaps some of these standard facilities will prove agreeable to you:

- edt.el --- enhanced EDT keypad mode emulation for GNU Emacs

  `edt-emulation-on` starts emulating DEC's EDT editor.  Do `edt-emulation-off` to return Emacs to normal.
- tpu-edt.el --- Emacs emulating TPU emulating EDT
- `vi-mode` or `vip-mode` or `viper-mode` starts emulating vi.

  - vi.el --- major mode for emulating "vi" editor under GNU Emacs
  - vip.el --- a VI Package for GNU Emacs
  - viper.el --- A full-featured Vi emulator for Emacs and XEmacs
- crisp.el --- CRiSP/Brief Emacs emulator

  `crisp-mode` enables an emulation for the CRiSP editor.
- ws-mode.el --- WordStar emulation mode for GNU Emacs

No longer available by default:

- `set-gosmacs-bindings` emulates Gosling Emacs.

  This command changes many global bindings to resemble those of
  Gosling Emacs.  The previous bindings are saved and can be restored using
  `set-gnu-bindings`.

Comment: You neglected to mention the most famous editor emulation package of all... `evil-mode` for Vim keybindings!

Comment: There are likely to be other third-party emulators as well.  This answer only covers built-in options, though.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)....

More seriously, Take the [tour](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs is a text editor, underneath all those layers of extra functionality  Just use Ctrl+X then Ctrl+F to open a file (or create a new one), or use “Find New File…” or “Open File…” from the “File” menu up top. To save, use Ctrl+X Ctrl+S. For more, I highly recommend [Xah Lee’s Emacs tutorials](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs.html)—they have all the tips you need to get you started. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is a text editor and it is fairly customizable.  Perhaps the most used customization is `cua-mode`, so you get the C-c as copy, C-v as paste, C-x as cut, key actions widely shared among other editors.  (Also, very ergonomic!)

Put this in your `~/.emacs` file:

```
    (cua-mode t)
    (setq cua-auto-tabify-rectangles nil) ;; Don't tabify after rectangle commands
    (transient-mark-mode 1) ;; No region when it is not highlighted
    (setq cua-keep-region-after-copy t) ;; Standard Windows behaviour
```

and restart emacs.  You question is so general, I'm guessing that is 90% of what you want, although I could be wrong.